# Everytime playing last audio files in UICollectionview

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

```
    - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return Arr_Audio.count;
    }
    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellAudio" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        UIView *view =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)];
        NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:[Arr_Audio objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        // create a player view controller
        avplayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
        controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,150,150);
        controller.player = avplayer;
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = NO;
        avplayer.closedCaptionDisplayEnabled = NO;
        [avplayer pause];


        [view addSubview:controller.view];
        [cell addSubview:view];


            playButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)];
            [playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_audio.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playPauseSelector:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [cell addSubview:playButton];

            return cell;
    }

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    _Audio_arr =[Arr_Audio objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _i=indexPath.row;
}



 // now how to play selected audio at collecion view.?
-(void)playPauseSelector:(UIButton *)button
{
    if (playValue)
    {
        //set pause image for button
        [playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_audio.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [avplayer pause];
    }
    else
    {
        //set play image for button
        [playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_playing.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [avplayer play];
    }
    playValue = !playValue;
}
```

Please tell me that how to play each audio for each cell. It is playing the last audio every time.

Comment: You need to add URL in button method. For this make in cellForItemAtIndexPath Method playButton.tag=indexpath.row. And in button method you can get easily row value. So now you can easily play audio when you click on particular cell.Before that you need to stop previous one.

Comment: how i can make? and if you have any code for this then keep in answer..plz and thank you for reply..@ KarthiK Mandava

Comment: Please put more effort into the description of the problem and into the language. This is  not the place for "kewl" abbreviations.

Comment: -(void)playPauseSelector:(UIButton *)button
{
    if (playValue)
    {
        //set pause image for button
        [playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_audio.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        
        [avplayer pause];
    }
    else
    {
         NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:[Arr_Audio objectAtIndex:button.tag]];
         avplayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
        //set play image for button
        [playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_playing.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [avplayer play];
    }
    playValue = !playValue;}

Comment: playButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)];
    playButton.tag=indexPath.row;
    [playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_audio.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playPauseSelector:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:playButton];

Comment: Add this in cellForItemAtIndexPath

Comment: Let me know it is working or not @Thumar Kishan

Comment: NO, its not working....still playing Last audio of the api list..@KarthiK Mandava

Comment: NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:[Arr_Audio objectAtIndex:button.tag]] see this in playPauseSelector method in else part.

Comment: i add that one but still didn't get tag.

Comment: Have you add tag value to playButton in cellForItemAtIndexPath ?

Comment: yes i add tage value in cellForItemAtIndexPath

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106094/discussion-between-karthik-mandava-and-thumar-kishan).